# How to setValue and getValue when using useFormContext in map Function React hook form

Tags: react-hook-form

How to setValues in textField and get Values when updates it.

Child Component

```
const MyTextField = () => {
const { control } = useFormContext()
<Controller control={control}
      name={name}
      render={({
        field: {onChange, onBlur, value},
        fieldState: { error }
      }) => {
        return (<TextField  fullWidth />
        )
      }} 
    />
  )
}

export default MyTextField
```

```
let data = [ 100, 200, 300]

  data.map(item => (<MyTextField name='price'  value={item} />)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to somehow transform the input value whenever it changes you can do this

```js
const MyTextField = () => {
const { control } = useFormContext()
<Controller control={control}
      name={name}
      render={({
        field,
        fieldState: { error }
      }) => {
        return (<TextField {...field}  fullWidth onChange={({target:{value}}) => {
        // do somethign with the value
        // and then call the field onChange to update the field state
        field.onChange(value)
        }} />
        )
      }} 
    />
  )
}

export default MyTextField
```

Yo don't need to call getValues while you're inside Controller, that's field.value for. If you wnat to get the input value outside the Controller then the getValue must be the one returned by useForm